# Redirect logged in user to new website with automatic authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one website designed in ASP.NET MVC 5 hosted with website name of [www.oldsite.com](http://www.oldsite.com).

We just now started a new website - [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com) with some changes to the ASP.NET MVC code and but database is the same for both sites.

When a user logs in to the old website, [www.oldsite.com](http://www.oldsite.com) verifies the login details (userid and password) and after successful login redirects the user based on some condition to new website [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com) with automatic login (user does not need to re-enter userid and password in login page again on [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com)) and shows the home page of [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com).

This is my code

```
int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 600 : 60; // 525600 min = 1 year
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(v.PEmailId, login.RememberMe, timeout);

string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;                        

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                 
if (some condition)
{
    return Redirect("www.newsite.com");
}
```

I need some login authentication cookies code, I am using ASP.NET identity.

Please tell me how to redirect from old site to new site [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com) with login credentials (give like userid and password parameter in login page and automatically login into new website) or how to create cookies for new website [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com) for automatic login without entering userid and password.

Answer (score -1):

From old site you can pass the username and password as parameter.

```
return Redirect(string.Format("https://newsite.com/Home/Index?username={0}&password={1}","username", "password"));
```

In new site create a function that allow anonymous users. Then validate the user credential. If the user is valid one then add cookies and redirect to the page you want.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
    {
        // validate the user credential
        // add cookie
        User user = new User();
        user.UserName = username;
        user.Password = password;
        AddCookie(user);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }

    public void AddCookie(User user)
    {
        string encryptTicket, userData;
        HttpCookie httpCookie = null;
        try
        {
            userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), true, userData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            encryptTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
        return httpCookie;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```